# Paging in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, page-index-changed

My gridView:

```
              <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"  emptydatatext="No data available." 
                    CssClass="datagrid" 
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                    onrowcreated="gridView1_RowCreated" 
                    onpageindexchanging="gridView1_PageIndexChanging">

                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

And my codebehind:

```
    protected void gridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindDataGrid();
    }



    protected void BindDataGrid()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds = dbM.GetInfo(name, mobilePhone, info1); //get info to BD and save in "ds"

        gridView1.DataSource = ds;
        gridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and the "Paging" does not work. It shows the first 5 rows, but does not show the number of paging

What´s wrong???

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some **pager settings** in the `GridView` tag:

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" />
```

If that works, you can change it to your desired appearance. There are [many choices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.aspx), including

- FirstPageImageUrl
- FirstPageText
- LastPageImageUrl
- LastPageText
- Mode (such as Numeric or
  NumericFirstLast)
- NextPageImageUrl
- NextPageText
- PageButtonCount
- Position
- PreviousPageImageUrl
- PreviousPageText
- Visible`

Answer (score 2):

Add the [PagerSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.visible%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)-Property to the GridView-Markup and set it to `True`:

```
PagerSettings-Visible="true"
```

Edit: but it should be `true` by default, so i'm not sure if this will change anything

Answer (score 2):

```
 Use **"PageIndexChanged"**

protected void gridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                BindDataGrid();
    ;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```