# GridView PageSize does not display

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

Here's the mark-up:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="gridView" ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    OnRowDataBound="gridview1_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gridview1_PageIndexChanging">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1B58B8" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#098ad3" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I don't know why but the other gridView with `AllowPaging` behaves normally but this one does not. It does not display the page numbers below the gridview. I use .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: May be not enough data?

Comment: try to change the page size, or check the data first.

Comment: @SabilValdano I've done that already, I use `DataTable` as `DataSource`, it has rows (8k plus), tried different page size but still it does not show up

Comment: try setting the `AllowCustomPaging="true"` property.

Comment: show me your binding code as well..

Answer (score 0):

First, is the `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` intentional? It seems you're binding data from code behind.

Second, maybe there is not enough data to display, i.e., below 10.

Comment: `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` is intentional. Meanwhile, there are actually 8k plus rows to display.

Answer (score 0):

@nathan742 i try your gridview code, and bind on my own data, and it works normally it shows the paging display, how about create on your own paging on databound :

I usually create custom gridview paging like this : [Custom Gridview Paging](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3499f4379040fa4b3346)

Comment: Yes, that code works for other pages. The gridview controls as what `PageSize` indicated, in my case `10`, it does that 10 rows per page but the page navigator below does not show up.

Comment: @nathan742 you should refer to this link [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224998/paging-gridview-problem?rq=1

Comment: or check your `CssClass="gridView" `